# aligning text with different number of lines css

Tags: html, css, text

I have a web page which have some boxes showing data from database .. the problem is i can't align the text at the same level

[image]

is there any way to make the text under services & distribution to be aligned with the others

that's my html

```
@foreach ($sections as $section)
<div class="sec">
<h3 class="section" > {{$section->name}} </h3>  
<p class="desc"> {{$section->description}}</p>
<a href="#" class="more"></a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

and that's my CSS

```
    .home_main .sec{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 1.5%;
        border:solid 2px ;
        border-color: #cfcfcf;
        width:17%;
        height: 29%;
    }

    .home_main .section{
        text-align: center;
        font: arial;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #494949;
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-right: 3px;
        margin-left: 3px;

    }

    .home_main .desc{
        color: #9e9e9e;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 2px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-top: 12%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
       display: -webkit-box;
       -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
       -webkit-line-clamp: 4; 
}

    .home_main a{
        width: 130px;
        height: 31px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 2%;
        margin-left: 2%;
        background:transparent url(../img/more.png) no-repeat;

    }
```

rendered HTML

```
<div class="sec">
<h3 class="section" > MNUFUCTIRONG </h3>    
<p class="desc"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet dictum leo ut placerat. Aenean dignissim sapien congue, sodales lacus at, accumsan lorem. Duis </p>
<a href="#" class="more"></a>
</div>
    <div class="sec">
<h3 class="section" > Real Estate  </h3>    
<p class="desc"> Industrial and Commercial zone 30 KM from Cairo (Obur City) - The zone serves production facilities for SMEs and bigger scale clients for warehousing , logistics services , and Retail spaces.</p>
<a href="#" class="more"></a>
</div>
    <div class="sec">
<h3 class="section" > START UPS </h3>   
<p class="desc"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet dictum leo ut placerat. Aenean dignissim sapien congue, sodales lacus at, accumsan lorem. Duis </p>
<a href="#" class="more"></a>
</div>
    <div class="sec">
<h3 class="section" > Seravices & Distribution  </h3>   
<p class="desc"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet dictum leo ut placerat. Aenean dignissim sapien congue, sodales lacus at, accumsan lorem. Duis </p>
<a href="#" class="more"></a>
</div>
    <div class="sec">
<h3 class="section" > FMCG </h3>    
<p class="desc"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed laoreet dictum leo ut placerat. Aenean dignissim sapien congue, sodales lacus at, accumsan lorem. Duis </p>
<a href="#" class="more"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your actual HTML, not whatever template that is.

Comment: @j08691
it's just the code getting data from the database

Comment: OK, post the rendered HTML so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The CSS you've shared doesn't reproduce what's there in the image at all...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need JavaScript to do this. The only way to make the boxes the same height is to display them as `table-cell`, and the only way to position the button and the text in the middle is using `position: absolute`, but that doesn't work inside table cells for some reason.

The only pure CSS change you might have it to display it as a table of 3X3 cells, where the first row contains the titles, the second row contains the texts and the third row contains the buttons. But I'm afraid you won't get the border like that in that setup, and of course it will affect your document structure in a negative way, since you will need to output the three titles first, so semantically your document becomes a mess.